# I keep getting this error on logging out of facebook, on an android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an app with user authentication in Facebook.  But it throws me the following error when I minimize, resume, and then log out of Facebook.

```
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-47
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1632)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.clearCookies(WebViewDatabase.java:543)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.clearAllCookies(CookieSyncManager.java:128)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at android.webkit.CookieManager$2.run(CookieManager.java:532)
07-13 16:35:42.989: E/AndroidRuntime(23464):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

And The Code Which generates the error is

```
       private void fbLogout() {
    dialog.setMessage("Disconnecting from Facebook");
    dialog.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v("fbLogout() Clear", "fbLogout() Clear");
            SessionStore.clear(getParent());

            int what = 1;                   
            try {
                Log.v("fbLogout() Clear", "fbLogout() before logout()");
                mFacebook.logout(getParent());
                Log.v("fbLogout() Clear", "fbLogout()after logout()");

                what = 0;
            } catch (Exception ex) {                
                ex.printStackTrace();                   
            }                   
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what));
        }
    }.start();
   }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        dialog.dismiss();           
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Facebook logout failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Disconnected from Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};




    public String logout(Context context)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Util.clearCookies(context);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();//Generates Error
    b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");//Generates Error
    String response = request(b);
    setAccessToken(null);
    setAccessExpires(0);
    return response;
```

Comment: I updated the question with Code

Answer (score 0):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
```

That says it all. Something is physically wrong with the device's internal storage. If your device is still under warranty, the carrier should replace it for you.

In future, consider doing more development on the emulator, so as to not put so much stress on your device's flash memory. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Web View of Facebook created its on database when first time you logging into the Application. and store its own database files into cache of the Application to save the Session.

I think you Are deleting the cache in your Application, so the database of webview is deleted Automatically. ans next time you try to logout from Facebook The DVM throws SQlite Data Base Exception.

just look into the File Explorer of your Emulator.
You might got any solution. :-)